# How to implement partial data update without specifying an identifier (pk) in the url-path?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am unloading all objects using **generics.UpdateAPIView** and **generics.ListCreateAPIView**:

**serializers.py:**

```py
class ProductSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    product_set = QuantitySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('code', 'name', 'price', 'product_set')
```

**views.py:**

```py
class ProductsList(generics.UpdateAPIView, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

**urls.py**:

```py
path('api/products/', views.ProductsList.as_view()),
path('api/product_detail/<int:pk>/', views.ProductQuantityDetail.as_view()),
```

Updating, adding data for an object is obtained if I go specifically along the path **api/product_detail/int:pk/**.

I would like to directly be able to partially update the data using the method PATCH/PUT in  **api/products/**, but I get the error:

> Expected view ProductsList to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

I would be glad for any help, maybe someone came across this.

Comment: how do you tell Django which row is going to be updated?

Comment: I copy the resulting json in content and manually change the value in the dictionary, then I press PATCH

Comment: Is there such a practice at all? We unload all objects on one page and want to somehow partially change the data of these objects ... Then how will the server generally understand which object to change?